# numpy: perform math on all combinations of vectors

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector

I have two arrays of vectors:

```
a = np.array([(1,0,0),(2,0,0),(3,0,0)...])
b = np.array([(0,1,0),(0,2,0),(0,3,0),(0,4,0)...])
```

They don't necessarily have the same length, but they might.

What I am looking for is a way to perform operations (add, dot, cross), on all combinations of vectors.

Examples:

Addition:

```
results = a+b
             a: (1,0,0)     (2,0,0)     (3,0,0) ...
   b:
(1,1,0)         (2,1,0)     (3,1,0)     (4,1,0)
(2,2,0)         (3,2,0)     (4,2,0)     (5,2,0)
(3,3,0)         (4,3,0)     (5,3,0)     (6,3,0)
...
results = [[(2,1,0),(3,1,0),(4,1,0)],[(3,2,0),(4,2,0),(5,2,0)],[(4,3,0),(5,3,0),(6,3,0)]]
```

Dot-Product:

```
results = a dot b
             a: (1,0,1)     (2,0,2)     (3,0,3) ...
   b:
(1,1,1)            2           4           6
(2,2,2)            4           8           12
(3,3,3)            6           12          18
...
results = [[2,4,6],[4,8,12],[6,12,18]]
```

Cross-Product:

```
results = a cross b
             a: (1,0,0)     (2,0,0)     (3,0,0) ...
   b:
(0,1,0)         (0,0,-1)    (0,0,-2)    (0,0,-3)
(0,2,0)         (0,0,-2)    (0,0,-4)    (0,0,-6)
(0,3,0)         (0,0,-3)    (0,0,-6)    (0,0,-9)
...
results = [[(0,0,-1), (0,0,-2), (0,0,-3)],[(0,0,-2),(0,0,-4),(0,0,-6)],[(0,0,-3), (0,0,-6), (0,0,-9)]]
```

I am aware that I could do that with a two loops like so:

```
results = []
for u in a:
   for v in b:
      results.append(u+v) #or u dot v or u cross v
```

However, that would defeat the purpose of using numpy, because it would be significantly slower than using builtin numpy functions. Therefore, what I am looking for is a way to perform np.add, np.dot and np.cross on the arrays a and b, but in a way where it goes over all possible combinations as mentioned above.

something like:
`results = np.cross_on_all_combination(a,b)`
or like
`results = np.cross(a[some magic here],b[some magic here])`

I would greatly appreciate hints on what to look for.

Comment: consider looking into how broadcasting works in numpy. `a + b[:,None]`, `np.einsum("ij, kij -> ik", a, b[:,:,None])` and `np.cross(a, b[:,None])` will give the correct results I believe.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In case of the dot product, it didn't quite work. The correct string to use was "ij, kjm -> ik", but you really put me on the right track. :)